# pgfplots: colorbar: align y ticklables to the right

Tags: pgfplots

I have a colorbar in pgfplots and would like to have the y tick labels aligned to the right.

Using

```
colorbar style={yticklabel style={align=right}}
```

did not work for me.

The left colorbar shows the default behaviour and the right the wanted bahaviour but with clumsy code (see MWE below).

[image: colorbar ticklabel aligned and not aligned]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
scale only axis,
height=0pt,
width=0pt,
colorbar,
point meta min=-20,
point meta max=20,
colorbar style={
    height=10cm,
}]
\addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[xshift=2cm]
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
scale only axis,
height=0pt,
width=0pt,
colorbar,
point meta min=-20,
point meta max=20,
colorbar style={
 yticklabel={$$},
    height=10cm,
}]
\addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}

\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xeval using 20-\x*4] in {0,1.25,...,10}
\node[anchor=east] at (1.75,-\x) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\xeval}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}![enter image description here][3]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess the problem is that the nodes containing the ticklabels are only as wide as the width of the individual ticklabel, so even if you align them `right`, that won't align them in relation to the other ticks.

A workaround would be to set the minimum width of the ticklabel nodes first, then change the alignment:

```
colorbar style={
    height=10cm,
    yticklabel style={text width=width("$-20$"),align=right}
}
```

You have to manually insert the widest ticklabel in `width("..")` though, so it's not entirely automatic.

(Note on `width` vs. `\widthof`: `pgf`/TikZ 2.x implemented a macro `\widthof` to calculate the width of some text. This was removed in version 3, but instead one can use the `width` function defined in the `pgf` math engine as seen above. There is a `\widthof` macro defined in the `calc` package though.)

Below I also added `draw` to the `yticklabel style`, to illustrate the point.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
scale only axis,
height=0pt,
width=0pt,
colorbar,
point meta min=-20,
point meta max=20,
colorbar style={
    height=10cm,yticklabel style={draw,align=right}
}]
\addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
scale only axis,
height=0pt,
width=0pt,
colorbar,
point meta min=-20,
point meta max=20,
colorbar style={
    height=10cm,yticklabel style={draw,text width=width("$-20$"),align=right}
}]
\addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[xshift=2cm]
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
scale only axis,
height=0pt,
width=0pt,
colorbar,
point meta min=-20,
point meta max=20,
colorbar style={
 yticklabel={$$},
    height=10cm,
}]
\addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}

\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \xeval using 20-\x*4] in {0,1.25,...,10}
\node[anchor=east] at (1.75,-\x) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\xeval}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hej Torbjørn - long time no see... Your works fine, thanks. I was hoping there would be an 'automatic' solution, but I can live with yours.

Comment: @Thethos Hello there, didn't recognize your profile image at first. Glad I could help.