# How to fix the width/length of ytick label in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to align three tikzpictures/pgfplots picture below each other. But they have different ytick labels (varying lenghts/widths). Check the attached screenshot.

Is there a possibility to determine a fixed length/width for the ytick labels?

[image]

Comment: Please add some code (MWE) to help us help you.

Comment: Yes, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145147/pgfplots-colorbar-align-y-ticklables-to-the-right/145152#145152 (Of course, don't add the `yticklabel style` within the `colorbar style`.)